# Processing: one file will write, other won't

Tags: processing, filewriter

I have a strange error which I really can't seem to find out. The situation is that I have an arduino board with a temperature and a light sensor: the light sensor is used to see if a certain room is 'open' (light goes out if there's no movement in the room for a certain time). I'm using a Serial port to push data to a server running a Processing script. The arduino board pushes 'OPEN' if the sensed light is above a certain treshhold, 'CLOSED' if it's not. It also pushes the temperature on a newline. It repeats every two seconds.

Monitoring the serial port with minicom that all seems to work fine. Even in the script, the data that I output confirms that everything should work fine. Except that when I try to write data to a 'open.txt' it seems to not to so, while the 'temp.txt' works fine (Tried to tail -f both files, temp.txt gets updated while open.txt just kept being empty.

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter openClosedFile;
 String openClosedFileName;
String currentOpenClosed;
PrintWriter temperatureFile;
String temperatureFileName;
int currentTemp;

void setup() 
{
   mySerial = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
   openClosedFileName = "open.txt";
   openClosedFile = createWriter(openClosedFileName);
   currentOpenClosed = "CLOSED";
   temperatureFileName = "temp.txt";
   temperatureFile = createWriter(temperatureFileName);
   currentTemp = 0;
}

void draw() 
{
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) 
    {
         String value = mySerial.readStringUntil('\n');
         if ( value != null ) 
         {
           String timestamp = nf(day(),2) + "/" + nf(month(), 2) + "/" + year() + " " +         nf(hour(),2) + ":" + nf(minute(),2) + ":" + nf(second(),2);
       println(timestamp);
       value = trim(value);
           if (isNumeral(value))
             writeTemperature(value);
           else
             writeOpenClosed(value);
         }
    }
}

void writeOpenClosed(String val)
{
  print("OpenClosed: ");
  println(val);
  boolean writtenToFile = false;
  openClosedFile = createWriter(openClosedFileName);
  if (val.equals("OPEN") && !currentOpenClosed.equals("OPEN"))
  {
    println("val=OPEN and currentOpenClosed!=OPEN");
    openClosedFile.print("1");
    writtenToFile = true;
  }
  else if (val.equals("CLOSED") && !currentOpenClosed.equals("CLOSED"))
  { 
    println("val=CLOSED and currentOpenClosed!=CLOSED");
    openClosedFile.print("0");
    writtenToFile = true;
  }

  if (writtenToFile)
  {
    currentOpenClosed = val;
    openClosedFile.flush();
    openClosedFile.close();
    println("Written OpenClosed To File");
  }
}

void writeTemperature(String val)
{
  print("temperature: ");
  println(val);
  int intTemp = Integer.parseInt(val);
  if (intTemp != currentTemp)
  {
    currentTemp = intTemp;
    temperatureFile = createWriter(temperatureFileName);
    temperatureFile.print(val);
    temperatureFile.flush();
    temperatureFile.close();
    println("Written Temperature To File");
  }
}

boolean isNumeral(String val)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++)
  {
    if (val.charAt(i) < 48 || val.charAt(i) > 57)
      return false;
  } 
  return true;
}
```

I expect there to be some syntactical error (I haven't used processing before), but both functions seems to be doing the same...

Some example output:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8212

30/10/2014 12:14:57
OpenClosed: CD
30/10/2014 12:14:57
temperature: 24
Written Temperature To File
30/10/2014 12:14:59
OpenClosed: CLOSED
30/10/2014 12:14:59
temperature: 25
Written Temperature To File
30/10/2014 12:15:01
OpenClosed: CLOSED
30/10/2014 12:15:01
temperature: 24
Written Temperature To File
30/10/2014 12:15:03
OpenClosed: CLOSED
30/10/2014 12:15:03
temperature: 25
Written Temperature To File
30/10/2014 12:15:05
OpenClosed: OPEN
val=OPEN and currentOpenClosed!=OPEN
Written OpenClosed To File
30/10/2014 12:15:05
temperature: 20
Written Temperature To File
30/10/2014 12:15:07
OpenClosed: OPEN
30/10/2014 12:15:07
temperature: 20
30/10/2014 12:15:09
OpenClosed: OPEN
30/10/2014 12:15:09
temperature: 20
^C
```

Am I not seeing something, or what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured it out, it was actually me being dumb.

For eventual future readers: calling

```
openClosedFile = createWriter(openClosedFileName);
```

in the writeOpenClosed() function will open the file, and if nothing has to be written it will never get closed. Since the file will never be closed (as there will be a new object made next time the function gets called), it won't release the file to be read.